# How to I create a "sub array-list" for an element of a main array-list?

Tags: java, arraylist, sub-array

I am trying to create a program to display vehicle "to-do" lists.  Here is an example of what I would want the output to look like.

```
 Blue Spitfire
      Sanding
           Hood
           Doors
      Engine
           Oil pan seal
      Electrical
           Oil pressure light
           Headlight switch
```

Right now, I have one ArrayList to store the vehicle name (Blue Spitfire).  I am wondering how to store the job names (sanding, engine, electrical) and the specifics (hood, doors, oil pan seal etc) under each job number.

To summarize, the vehicle name stores the jobs, and the jobs store the specifics.  How do I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Java is an **Object-Oriented** language. Use it. Create classes, e.g. `Vehicle`, `Job`, and `Part`

Comment: class Vehicle { ArrayList<job> jobs =new ArrayList<>();} class Job { ArrayList<Part> jobSpecifics = new ArrayList<>();}

Comment: Maybe : `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainArray = new ArrayList()` ?
Not sure of what you really want

Comment: I have the ArrayList to store the vehicle name.  I just don't know how to store the job and job specifics under a specific vehicle or specific job

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map, specifically a HashMap to store the list of associations between keys and values, and use either a List or a Set, specifically a HashSet, to store the lists of values.

But as noted in the comments, it may be better to use a combination of that and classes.

Here's one possible implementation. (You could make it shorter using utility classes for creating Sets and Maps, such as those from the Google Guava library or Apache Commons library.)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Job {
    String model;
    Map<String, Set<String>> areas;

    public Job(String model, Map<String, Set<String>> areas) {
        this.model = model;
        this.areas = areas;
    }

}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> areas = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> sandingProblems = new HashSet<>();
        sandingProblems.add("Hood");
        sandingProblems.add("Doors");
        areas.put("Sanding", sandingProblems);
        Set<String> engineProblems = new HashSet<>();
        engineProblems.add("Oil panel seal");
        areas.put("Engine", engineProblems);
        Set<String> electricalProblems = new HashSet<>();
        electricalProblems.add("Oil pressure light");
        electricalProblems.add("Headlight switch");
        areas.put("Electrical", electricalProblems);
        Job job = new Job("Blue Spitfire", areas);

        System.out.println(job.model);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : areas.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + entry.getKey());
            for (String problem : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("\t\t" + problem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix my problem with ArrayLists?  My education in programming ends at grade 12.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend limiting yourself to a particular grade level of code. Classes and maps are programming 101 so if you dont learn them at some point, you're in for a rough time.

Comment: I will look into it.  I will not use programming in a future career, but I am open to learning!

Comment: I've added a full example that builds up the structures and then prints them out in the same format you had in your question. You should be able to take the sample code, put it into a file named "Example.java", compile it and run it.

Comment: I will try it out.  Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Vehicle {
    
    Vehicle(String vName) {
        vehicleName= vName;
    }
    String vehicleName;
    ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

    void addJob(Job j) {
        jobs.add(j);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String returnString = vehicleName ;
        for (Job j: jobs) {
            returnString = returnString+ "\r\n\t"+ j.jobName;
            for (String jobSpecifics: j.jobsSpecifics) {
                returnString = returnString+ "\r\n\t\t"+ jobSpecifics;
            }
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}

class Job {
    String jobName;
    ArrayList<String> jobsSpecifics = new ArrayList<>();
    Job(String jobName) {
        this.jobName= jobName;
    }
    void addJobSpecifics(String s) {
        jobsSpecifics.add (s);
    }
}

public class VehicleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle("Blue Spitfire");
        Job j= new Job("Sanding");
        j.addJobSpecifics("Hood");
        j.addJobSpecifics("Doors");
        v.addJob(j);
        System.out.println(v);
        }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you amend this code to spell `Vechicle` as `Vehicle`?